# How to add a List of list to an existing data frame as separate columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['aa', 1], ['bb', 2], ['cc', 3]])

    0   1
0   aa  1
1   bb  2
2   cc  3
```

how can i add a list of lists `li = [['xx',11], ['yy',22], ['zz',33]]` to the data frame `df` so that each list inside the `li` will be added as a row . Expected output is as below:

```
    0   1   2   3
0   aa  1   xx  11
1   bb  2   yy  22
2   cc  3   zz  33
```

currently i am looping through indexes of sublist and adding them to `df`

```
for i in range(len(li[0])):
    df[str(df.shape[1])] = [x[i] for x in li]
```

is there any simpler way to do this without looping?

> `len(df)` always equals to `len(li)`
>   all sublists in `li` are of the same length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) as:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(li, columns=df.columns+2))

print(df)
    0  1   2   3
0  aa  1  xx  11
1  bb  2  yy  22
2  cc  3  zz  33
```

If the number of columns vary dynamically then:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(li, columns=df.columns+df.shape[1]))
```

If the number of columns are different then:

```
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(li, columns=np.arange(len(li[0]))+df.shape[1]))
```

Comment: the number of columns can vary, so `columns= df.columns+df.shape[1]`.

Comment: @Shijith Sure, added.

Comment: this will fail if `no. of columns in df != len of sublist`, i.e. if my df has 3 columns , this will fail if i try to add the same `li`